# Gdx exit closing entire application - how to close only the gdx frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, libgdx, lwjgl

I have a game editor, in which it is possible to launch the game being edited in a separate window (but within the same VM). However, when the game is closed, I would like to close its gdx window, without bringing down the whole application (that is, the editor).

I am currently using the following code inside the JFrame that hosts the `LwjglApplication`:

```
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    System.err.println("Now closing app...");
    Gdx.app.exit();
    System.err.println("App now closed.");
}
```

This prints the goodbye, closes the GDX window, and proceeds to terminate my VM. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the desktop (lwjgl backend) `Gdx.app.exit()` posts a Runnable that causes the loop `mainLoop` to complete and control to fall out the bottom of that function (see [the source](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java#L338)).  The [mainLoop ends with](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java#L206):

```
if (graphics.config.forceExit) System.exit(-1);
```

The `graphics.config` is the [`LwjglApplicationConfiguration`](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplicationConfiguration.java#L31) object passed in [`LwjglApplication` constructor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java#L62).  So just set

```
config.exit = false
```

in the config object (you may need to create one and use a different constructor if you're not currently creating a config object).  There are other handy things you can set in the config object, too.

(This code is from GIT, so things may be different in older version of GDX or with other backends.)